# React+JavaScript:: Using Api in react to print data by user in console, but then after submitting it disappears from console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to console log the data entered by user from my sign up page. However, the item appears in the console for about a second and then disappears.

API

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL = 'http://localhost:5000';

export const authenticateSignup = async (data) => {
    try {
        return await axios.post(`${URL}/signup`, data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while calling signup api', error);
    }
}
```

Register Page

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, FormGroup, Input } from "reactstrap";
import Helmet from "../components/Helmet/Helmet";
import CommonSection from "../components/UI/CommonSection";
import { authenticateSignup } from "../service/api";


import "../styles/contact.css";

const socialLinks = [
  {
    url: "#",
    icon: "ri-facebook-line",
  },
  {
    url: "#",
    icon: "ri-instagram-line",
  },
  {
    url: "#",
    icon: "ri-linkedin-line",
  },
  {
    url: "#",
    icon: "ri-twitter-line",
  },
];


const signupIntialValues = { 
  firstname: '',
  lastname: '',
  username: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
  password: ''
}

const VehicleSharing = () => {
  const [signup, setSignup] = useState(signupIntialValues);

  const onInputChange = (e) => { 
     setSignup({ ...signup, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); 
  }

  const signupUser = async () => { 
    let response = await authenticateSignup(signup);
  }
  
  

  return (
    <Helmet title="Register or Sign Up">
      <CommonSection title="Register or Sign Up" />
      <section>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="7" md="7">
              <h6 className="fw-bold mb-4">Create your account. It's free and only takes a  minute.</h6>

              <Form>
                <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <Input placeholder="First Name" type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} name='firstname'/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <Input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} name='lastname'/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <Input placeholder="User Name" type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} name='username'/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <Input placeholder="Email" type="email" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} name='email'/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <Input placeholder="Mobile Number" type="tel" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} name='phone'/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <Input placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} name='password'/>
                </FormGroup>
              
                {/* <FormGroup className="contact__form">
                  <textarea
                    rows="5"
                    placeholder="Message"
                    className="textarea"
                  ></textarea>
                </FormGroup> */}
                
                

                <button className=" contact__btn" type = "submit" onClick={() => signupUser()}>
                  Sign Up
                </button>
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                Already registered <Link to="/Login">Sign In?</Link>
                </p>
              </Form>
            </Col>

            <Col lg="5" md="5">
              <div className="contact__info">
                <h6 className="fw-bold">Contact Information</h6>
                <p className="section__description mb-0">
                139, CHARUSAT Campus, Highway, Off, Nadiad - Petlad Rd, Changa, Gujarat 388421
                </p>
                <div className=" d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
                  <h6 className="fs-6 mb-0">Phone:</h6>
                  <p className="section__description mb-0">+918890596286</p>
                </div>

                <div className=" d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
                  <h6 className="mb-0 fs-6">Email:</h6>
                  <p className="section__description mb-0">htr5602@gmail.com</p>
                </div>

                <h6 className="fw-bold mt-4">Follow Us</h6>

                <div className=" d-flex align-items-center gap-4 mt-3">
                  {socialLinks.map((item, index) => (
                    <Link
                      to={item.url}
                      key={index}
                      className="social__link-icon"
                    >
                      <i class={item.icon}></i>
                    </Link>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
    </Helmet>
  );
};

export default VehicleSharing;
```

Comment: please mention where you are using console.log data and after clicking what function it showing

Comment: I want to fetch this data and add it in the MongoDB database furthur. But while testing the API it is not staying in the console and disappears from it after clicking submit button.

Comment: use  e.preventDefault(); event https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html